# How do I make a landscape like this? (Sea, waves, shore, beach...)

Tags: 3d-view

How do I make a landscape as shown below?

[image]

This is something which I am getting using ANT landscape tool and TXA_ant but it nothing close to what I need,[image]

Comment: You could start here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=df2f_mcZhkE&ab_channel=cgDroid OR https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHg-CHcflPM&t=934s&ab_channel=CGGeek ?

Comment: Hello :). Looks rather easy. What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck? Do you need any part to be animated?

Comment: Hello. What have you tried so far and which difficulties have you encountered?

Comment: I just needed a static model with transparent water.I am using ANT Landscape tool but I am left unguided and taking lot of time since I am a beginner to blender.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create 2 objects, one for the ground:

[image]

Select some random vertices and move them up:

[image]

Extrude the whole plane down:

[image]

Create the sea:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Give it a *Displace* modifier with a texture *Cloud* in order to have a bit of noise, with *Coordinates > Object* and an empty as *Object* that you will move and keyframe. At last, give it a *Wave* modifier with this kind of settings:

[image]

Now give a texture to the ground that is basically a gradient on the Z axis:

[image]

Give a texture to the water that is a mix between *Glass, Transparent* and *Glossy*:

[image]

Give your whole scene an HDRI:

[image]

If you're supposed to make a part of your water flater (or decrease the modifiers effect), switch your sea object to *Weight Paint* mode, paint this part:

[image]

Then in the modifiers, select the group you've just selected, switch with the <-> button:

[image]

Comment: I've noticed just now that the big stone is Suzanne! Good one :)

Comment: You started the challenge!

Comment: "choose an empty as object that you scale on the X axis in order to stretch the cloud texture and create parallel waves" This part how do I get it to make waves?

Comment: you need to create an empty, then give your water object a Displace modifier, in this modifier click New and in the Properties panel > Texture > Type, choose Cloud. Then back to your modifier, choose Coordinates > Object, and then choose the empty as Object and choose Direction > Z. Now play with the empty scale to stretch the waves. Give a Subdivision Surface modifier to your object to smooth it.

Comment: What is empty? How do I make the empty?

Comment: Shift A > Empty

Comment: I got everything as said in the answer and is really awesome. Just one thing, to make it exactly like in the question image how to make those parallel waves?

Comment: There's an Ocean modifier that gives rather good wave simulations, but if you scale the empty enough with the current solution it will create more visible waves. Also, if you work with Cycles, you can try with a Wave node plugged into the Displacement node, tell me if you want to me to explain more in details.

Comment: I am trying to recreate the model in blender but after several tries, it is not coming exactly like in the image.,.so pls help

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and will let u know. One more advice from u is that if I want to make the a change in the wave by putting an L-shaped bar(as in the pic) I can use sculpt tool to do that right?

Comment: The bar I already made but if I want to modify the wave. Ie, the bar helps to reduce the wave intensity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115836/discussion-between-gokul-anand-and-moonboots).

Comment: OK I understand, I've edited again, please take a look